# Access nested nodes with GraphQL (Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

i’m experiencing some issues with Apollo, GraphQL and Nuxt. i don’t know if it’s especially related to Nuxt though, or with vue.

i’m trying to use WordPress as headless CMS via WP-GraphQL plugin. here’s my query

[WP-GraphQL interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma1Dh.png)

i basically created a graphql folder with a posts.js file inside, that contains my query

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export const myQuery = gql`
  query myQuery {
    posts {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        date
        slug
        author {
          node {
            name
          }
        }
        featuredImage {
          node {
            uri
            sourceUrl
            srcSet
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

then, all i need to do is to print my data in the template. here's the script part first.

```
<script>
import { myQuery } from '~/graphql/posts'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    }
  },

  apollo: {
    posts: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: myQuery,
    },
  },

  watch: {
    async $route() {
      await this.$nuxt.refresh()
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    },
  },
  transition: 'home',

  async mounted() {
    this.posts = await this.$apollo.query({ query: myQuery })
    this.posts = this.posts.data.posts.nodes
    this.loading = false
}
</script>
```

and then comes the template :

```
<template>
    <section class="featured-projects">
      <div class="featured-projects__wrapper">
        <article v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
          <p>{{ post.id }}</p>
          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
          <span>{{ post.date }}</span>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>
```

everything just works!

now, i would like to print post author name as well. i first tried this :

```
<span>{{ post.author }}</span>
```

and this actually prints this :

```js
{
    "node": {
        "name": "max max",
        "__typename": "User"
    },
    "__typename": "NodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge"
}
```

it totally makes sense, as author is an object with nested items in it. so according to what i’m being returned and following GraphQL API structure, to display post author name, think i should do something like this instead :

```
<span>{{ post.author.node.name }}</span>
```

and here’s the error i get, and i don’t know what to do to access what i want :
Cannot read property 'node' of undefined.

Comment: From the error message we can assume that `post.author` is `undefined` in this case. Are you sure that every post even has an author associated with it? Maybe print the result of your api request to the console to have a look, or add it to your question if you need further help.

Comment: show more code/repo/sandbox with structure/details

Comment: yes, post.author exists and i can even log it inside a mounted() hook. for instance, if i try to log post.author[0].node.name, it's going to print the correct author name. the problem seems to come from somewhere else..

i have written 4 articles in the WordPress backoffice, and yes, each article does have a corresponding author. i'll try to post more code so that debugging is easier

Comment: don't trust `console.log()`, it's not fully reliable, can be 'magically' updated by browser 'user friendly' logic ... yes, author must exist in WP post ... again/still, show code/usage ... or use react/gatsby/next :p

Comment: alright! then, it does exist in WP but probably not in the app (at least, it does not exist yet when i try to print it). if it can help debugging, i just posted the entire index.vue file as an answer to this topic ;)

btw, thank you so much for taking some time to read this stuff and assisting me.

Comment: `console.log (this.posts)` in `mounted` - check data structure ... add `id` (in query) for author node (and for image, too) - required by apollo [normalizing] cache

Comment: `this.posts` returns an array of 4 items (my four articles) with a structure i would have expected. author (such as featuredImage) are 'observers' objects though, and i don't exactly understand what it means.

i'll try to add `id` in the query, i have to figure this out as i don't know how i can do this yet

Comment: just extend your query in author part (click checkbox in playground) ... hmmm, some vue-specific (or vue-apollo) magic IDK, see docs

Comment: tried to add `id` in the query but does not change anything. yeah, i'mma check the docs again and try digging somewhere else for now. thanks though, your help is grandly appreciated!

Comment: What if you move your code to a `async fetch()`hook rather than `mounted()` and make your template wait for fetch to be done with `v-if="$fetchState.pending"`?

Comment: why query twice? perhaps remove the prefetch line -  also the mounted call to apollo is redundant according to https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query

Answer (score 1):

your problem arises from reading the data before it is loaded.

depending on your js settings you should be able to use one of the following:

`<span>{{ post?.author.node.name }}</span>`

or `<span>{{ post ? post.author.node.name : '' }}</span>`

---

according to the Vue Apollo documentation it could also be a problem with the duplication of the query

```html
<script>
import { myQuery } from '~/graphql/posts'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [], // initialization
    }
  },

  apollo: {
    posts: {
      prefetch: false, // to prevent SSR
      query: myQuery,
      update: data => {
        console.log('overwrite posts with new data', data.posts)
        return data.posts
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

further as there seem to be cases in which the author has more than one entry (perhaps co authors?) I would try to update the author rendering to the following:

```html
<template>
    <section class="featured-projects">
      <div class="featured-projects__wrapper">
        <article v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
          <p>{{ post.id }}</p>
          <div v-if="Array.isArray(post.author)">
            first author is: {{ post.author[0].node.name }}
          </div>
          <div v-else-if="post.author">
           author is: {{ post.author.node.name }}
          </div>
          <div v-else="post.author">
           no author
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer!
it does not seem to work for me, none of the proposals you made succeeds.

i still have an "Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" error that is being returned

Comment: I have the assumption that there is something else happening, what about an introspect of the graphql type for the author? I assume based on another comment of you that it is an array. `post.author[0].node.name`